# Can we say ,"Behave as an adult." to an adult?

Tags: word-choice

When adressing an adult, which sentence is correct?
"Behave as an adult." or " Behave like an adult."

Comment: I'd go to the safe side and use *like*. *As* is also used for similarities, but not always in the same conditions.

Comment: Can you say it in your native language?

Answer (score 4):

You can say

> Act your age!Don't be childish!

This can be told to someone behaving in a stupid way as if they were younger than they really are.

Answer (score 2):

> Behave like an adult!
>   Be an adult, will you!
>   What are you doing? You're an adult!
>   Act your age, not your IQ!
>   [Act you age not your shoe size](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hTSOT55qsZw&t=2m54s)
>   [Oh, grow up please!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uGr-LgtV_NI&t=6m50s)

are all expressions that can be used to tell an adult to stop behaving immaturely.

Comment: Some more insulting than others.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct grammatically and convey the same meaning, but the use of like instead of as is more common.

You can also say:

Don't be (so) childish!

Come on! You aren't a child.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=behave+as+an+adult%2C+behave+like+an+adult&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbehave%20as%20an%20adult%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbehave%20like%20an%20adult%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1):

In British English a common phrase implying criticism of how someone is behaving childishly is simply

**Grow up!**

The expression

**Man up**

seems to be gaining popularity, with the sense of encouraging somebody to behave like an adult, rather than criticising them for not doing so. (I have no idea what is the female equivalent of "man up.")